# Visual Studio (Visual Macro) doesn't include Arduino libraries

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, arduino-ide

First, I'm sorry if it's not the proper place to ask this question. I'm not sure whether I should post it here or on Electronics Stack Exchange.

I use "Visual Micro" add-ons in Visual Studio 13 for Arduino. Normally, it works fine. But for my project I had to download these two library files, "Adafruit_SSD1306" and "Adafruit_GFX". Arduino IDE works fine but Visual Studio can't include them. It can't even include "Wire.h" but perfectly includes "SPI.h" header where both of them are in same directory. I included those files directories in project properties. But when I run "Build" it gives a fatal error:

[image: Fatal Error]

And stops compilation. Same error occurs for the remaining two include files.

Can any one point out any mistakes I made, or suggest any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Screenshot of project properties:

[image]

Comment: Doing `#include <filename.h>` will only search for `filename.h` in the header libraries. Your project properties must be wrong -  add a screenshot of the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I made a very silly mistake that most of the time is not worth to look for. This is just crap.

There is no space between "#include" and `<Wire.h>` and so the compiler is reading this as a whole sentence. If I write:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
```

instead of

```
#include<Wire.h>
#include<Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include<Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
```

Then everything is fine.

How silly I am.  -_-

Comment: I'd rather call the compiler silly which reports _No such file ..._ there.